# How many different posets, well-order relations are there on a set of size n.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory, well-orders

can any one help me i can't find total number of partial orders on a set of size n
also help me with total number of well-orders on a set of size n ..

OEIS has Number of partially ordered sets ("posets") with n labeled elements . but there is no formula i can find on internet to to calculate number of posets ?

https://oeis.org/A000112

Comment: I believe you are referring to https://oeis.org/A000112 – it is true that there is no formula there, but (1) there are about 60 references and links, which should keep you busy for a while, and (2) as there's no formula given there, and as only the first 16 terms have been calculated, that's a very strong hint that no formula is known. Also: your title suggests you are interested in three different questions: (1) posets, (2) total orders, and (3) well-ordered relations. Is that right? (the body of the post only mentions the posets). What's a well-ordered relation?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! It would be great if you could state (as an edit to your question) your attempts / ideas regarding this problem, even if they have not been successful. Also, you mention that OEIS has a result on a similar (though not the same) problem: perhaps you could provide a link to that page / sketch their result in your question itself? That might be helpful for people trying to provide an answer.

Comment: Why does the title mention total orders and well orders? General posts are neither, and the body of the question doesn’t mention total orders or well orders again.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you i edited it

Comment: [A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035) "Number of partially ordered sets with n labeled elements." There is no formula in the OEIS entry which is a very strong hint that there is no known formula.

Comment: Since we're only talking about finite sets, how does a well-order differ from a total order?

Comment: I say, how does a well-order differ from a total order?

Comment: @GerryMyerson for a well order relation ,it's a total order but every non-empty subset of well order must have a least element , i am new to this as far as my notes i was sure this is true.

Comment: Sure, but we're dealing with finite sets here, and a total order on a finite set has to be a well-order, no? Every nonempty subset of a  finite totally ordered set is guaranteed to have a least element, right? It's only for infinite sets that well-ordering is an issue.

Comment: @GerryMyerson then it would have same no of relation for both total order and well order which would be $n!$ thank you.